# Mathematica Kernels in a remote machine via port forwarding and no public password

Tags: front-end, kernel, remote-access

I would like to launching Mathematica kernels on a remote machine.

Port forwarding is required to connect to this machine. I usually need to connect to a machine via ssh port forwarding and then in another terminal window I can have access to the remote machine.

I tried to use Tunnel (https://github.com/sakra/Tunnel) to do it.

However both the forwarding machine and the remote machine require a password and the public key is disabled, and Tunnel doesn't ask me the passwords when it tries to open the connection.

Is there a way to do it?