# Keep kernels alive in parallel evaluations of several scripts

Tags: parallelization, scripting

I have written a parallel script file that after initializing the kernels it puts the result of some computation in a file. I provide some external parameters to the script. I would like to run the script several times with different parameters, however every time the script runs it inizialises again the kernels, wasting a lot of time.

The script structure is something like

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
LaunchKernels[4];
param = ToExpression[ $ScriptCommandLine[[2]] ];

dat=ParallelTable[RandomReal[],{j,param}];
MaxDat=Max[dat];

s=OpenWrite["datafile.txt"];
WriteString[s,param<>"  "<>ToString@MaxDat<>"\n"];
Close[s];
```

and I run in terminal through, for instance for param=2 and param=3

```
wolframscript -script prova.wls 2
wolframscript -script prova.wls 3
```

Every time I called the command the script launches the kernels. It is possible to inizializes the kernels only during the first run and keep them opened? I had a look at similar questions but I did not find the answer.

Comment: Why do you insist on invoking `wolframscript` many times with command line parameters? You could write a single program that runs once and does everything you need, for all parameters.  Running "scripts" like this is not the most effective way of using Mathematica.  If each run is so fast that the time to start parallel kernels matters, why are you even using the command line instead of the notebook interface?

Comment: I agree with you, but I need to keep a ssh session alive from remote and I am trying to follow the suggestion in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151981/keep-mathematica-session-alive-on-ssh?noredirect=1#comment406611_151981.   The computation of every script is not slow compared with the initialization time of the kernels (it depends on the value of the parameter...the code I showed you it is just an example), however it is unnecessary, and I am trying to understand whether it is possible to avoid it.

Comment: That explains why you don't want to use notebooks, but I still do not see why you want a separate run for each parameter value.

Comment: I need to analyse the data with some parameters before choosing whether or not generate further data...the choice of the parameter I put depends on the partial results (I cannot automate this stage, unfortunately).

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't just run everything in Mathematica instead of invoking multiple scripts from the shell.  Mathematica runs interactively, so you can use it even for tasks that require human decision from time to time.  The `screen` utility helps you run it on the server, disconnect, reconnect, and still find it where it was.

Comment: screen or tmux does not keep a remote notebook session alive (see also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147639/mathematica-kernels-in-a-remote-machine-via-port-forwarding-and-no-public-passwo). Moreover when a notebook interface is used by remote, typing is very slow and basically so annoying that is useless.

Comment: I found very comfortable using scripts in this way for the specific task I am doing now....I just don't want to initialize the kernels in each script..it is possible or not?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: as I said, you must not restart the kernel. You seem to be making your life difficult for no good reason.  I did not say that `screen` allows using a notebook session. I said that you can use Mathematica interactively with it (from the command line).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, even I remove the Lanchkernels command from my script, because I have ParallelTable commands, every times the script is executed the kernels are initialized. Unless there is a way to launch a script directly from inside the Mathematica shell I do not see how to do it.

Comment: Well of course there is, see `Get` ... That's my point. *Why do you insist on launching **separate** scripts from the unix shell?*  What does the unix shell give you that Mathematica cannot (other than pain and suffering :P )?

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know that scripts could be run directly from the Mathematica shell. This was exactly what I was looking for... in any case to initialize the parameters I used  Block[{par=...},<<scriptfilename.wls]

Comment: The caveat is that definitions/variables will not be clearer between running two "scripts".  What I do personally is that I wrap up the whole program into a function, and try to avoid using global variables.  Then I call the functions with different parameter values.  If you already have scripts using global variables, your approach with `Block` should work too.

Comment: ok I see your point. thanks a lot!